# Getting ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error in SQL trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting below error in the web methods adapter on the table which has the MIH_TRIGGER.

> (65000/6502) ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to
>   number conversion error ORA-06512: at
>   "B2B_OPS_BUILD_ADMIN.MIH_TRIGGER", line 2 ORA-04088: error during
>   execution of trigger 'B2B_OPS_BUILD_ADMIN.MIH_TRIGGER'

Below is the MIH_TRIGGER fore reference which will update the data from OPS_BUILD_MIH table to OPS_BUILD_AUDITLOG table whenever OFFSET column is updated.

The OFFSET column in OPS_BUILD_MIH is NUMBER

The OLD_VALUE and NEW_VALUE columns in OPS_BUILD_AUDITLOG are VARCHAR2(100).

I'm trying to insert a numeric value which is in OFFSET column into the OLD_VALUE and NEW_VALUE varchar2 columns and getting this error.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "B2B_OPS_BUILD_ADMIN"."MIH_TRIGGER" 
AFTER UPDATE OF OFFSET
ON OPS_BUILD_MIH
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if ( nvl(:OLD.OFFSET,'xYz#@!0') != nvl(:NEW.OFFSET,'xYz#@!0')) then
  INSERT INTO OPS_BUILD_AUDITLOG
    (TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME,
     OLD_VALUE,
     NEW_VALUE,
     UPDATED_BY,
     UPDATED_DTM,
     UUID)
  VALUES  
    ('OPS_BUILD_MIH',
     'OFFSET',
     :OLD.OFFSET,
     :NEW.OFFSET,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DTM,
     :OLD.MIH_ID);
 end if;

END;
```

Can you please suggest a fix for this so that I can modify the above trigger accordingly.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Regards
Phani

Comment: OFFSET column is number, but your checking nvl(offset, 'xYz#@!0'). This is wrong. In NVL both arguments should be same datatype

Comment: Show the definitions of the tables `OPS_BUILD_MIH` and `OPS_BUILD_AUDITLOG`. It gets easier for people to simulate your issue.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik for the quick look.
Without this 'xYz#@!’ expression we are getting compilation error for nvl(:OLD.OFFSET,'xYz#@!') != nvl(:NEW.OFFSET,'xYz#@!’) hence it is there.
Do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: OPS_BUILD_MIH Table:
Name                    Null     Type          
----------------------- -------- ------------- 
MIH_ID                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)  
LOB                              VARCHAR2(40)  
OFFSET                  NOT NULL NUMBER        
PROGRAM_ID              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)  
SITE_ID                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)  
ACTIVITY_LABEL_ID       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)

Comment: Below is the structure of OPS_BUILD_AUDITLOG
Name        Null Type          
----------- ---- ------------- 
TABLE_NAME       VARCHAR2(40)  
COLUMN_NAME      VARCHAR2(40)  
OLD_VALUE        VARCHAR2(400) 
NEW_VALUE        VARCHAR2(400)

Comment: Btw, you should put extra information in your question (there's an edit button you can click that will allow you to update your question), and properly format it (there's the {} code button when you edit the question, or you can simply prepend each row with four spaces).

Answer (score 2):

As Gaj has already pointed out, the issue lies with your NVL - you're trying to compare a non-numeric string to a number, which won't work.

Whilst you could change the NVL to check for a numeric value you will never encounter, it would be far better to change the condition to:

```
:OLD.OFFSET != :NEW.OFFSET
or (:OLD.OFFSET is not null and :NEW.OFFSET is null)
or (:OLD.OFFSET is null and :NEW.OFFSET is not null)
```

That way, you don't have to make up a magic number that your actual values could never be; assuming such a number even exists!